# Meizu devices on Android 5.x trigger: SQLiteException: table httpauth already exists

Tags: android, android-sqlite

A couple of weeks ago I started seeing crash reports for my Android app with the following stack trace.
This happens exclusively on Meizu devices running android 5.x
This crash isn't related to my app, but I would like to know if you have any information on how to prevent this (ROM setting, WebView workaround, ...)
I cannot find any information on this bug on Google...

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table httpauth already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE httpauth (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, host TEXT, realm TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT, UNIQUE (host, realm) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java)
   at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.createTable(HttpAuthDatabase.java)
   at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.initDatabase(HttpAuthDatabase.java)
   at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.initOnBackgroundThread(HttpAuthDatabase.java)
   at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.access$000(HttpAuthDatabase.java)
   at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase$1.run(HttpAuthDatabase.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, You can drop the table with DROP TABLE IF EXISTS or in the other hand you can create with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: Please take a look at my question and at the stacktrace. This table has nothing to do with my app. I don't have any httpauth table in my database. It looks like a system table/bug.
I'm looking for a workaround or a way to disable this in the device settings

Comment: oh, discard my solution. My fault

Answer (score 0):

I met the samething and I can't found anything useful.
I think  it cause by the Flyme OS (MeiZu devices).

```html
Version: 6.1.1(594)
Android: 5.1(MX4)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table httpauth already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE httpauth (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, host TEXT, realm TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT, UNIQUE (host, realm) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
 at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.createTable(HttpAuthDatabase.java:132)
 at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.initDatabase(HttpAuthDatabase.java:123)
 at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.initOnBackgroundThread(HttpAuthDatabase.java:90)
 at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase.access$000(HttpAuthDatabase.java:29)
 at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.HttpAuthDatabase$1.run(HttpAuthDatabase.java:69)
```